# Why does Replace '&' with '&amp;' not work for XML data?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

I need to download a XML file and its data is retrieved from stored procedure.
My problem is if the data contains any '&' symbol, in XML file it is showing as

```
'&amp;'
```

I have used REPLACE function in my Procedure as shown below but...

```sql
SELECT @V_NAME = REPLACE(@V_NAME, ' & ', ' &amp; ');

UPDATE #TMP_RS_XML
SET OBJECT_ID=@V_ID,
    FNAME=@V_FILE,
    DOCUMENT=(SELECT @V_NAME as 'Description',
    ...
```

Now, the output is:

```
&amp;amp;
```

Comment: `&amp;` is the XML encoding for `&` because `&` is a special character.

Comment: As to why your replacement "doesn't work", you're replacing `&` with `&amp;`, not `&amp;` with `&`. But as juharr says, &amp; is the XML encoded form of `&`, so you shouldn't remove it.

Comment: So, you replace the `&` character with `&amp;`. When replacing `&` in `&amp;` in this manner, of course the result is `&amp;amp;`. It could not be anything else.

Comment: You probably have an XML embedded in a html document.  You need to use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) or System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Before using replace function, for ex: `E.R. MANAGEMENT &amp; CO. KG` was shown instead of `E.R. MANAGEMENT & CO. KG`. I found in net that we need to replace all `&` with `&amp;` so we will get `&` in our XML doc. That's why i used such replacement.

Comment: You do have `&` in your XML doc. It is required that the `&`, while it is in an XML doc, is stored as `&amp;`. It is not correct to have a raw `&` in an XML doc, that makes it invalid XML doc. You do not have `&amp;` in your XML doc, you have `&`. Any code that reads this information from XML will read `&`. That is, unless you are using a homebrew "parser" that takes the data out of an XML string using `Substring` or the sort, in which case please do not do that.

Comment: @LimnaD'silva You use a XML library to read/change/use XML data, so you don't have to deal with this. Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way this is supposed to work...

XML is not just some *text with fancy extras* but with very strict rules. As any *text-based* container you will need either *magic words* or *special characters* to tell the consumer what is the content and what is the markup.

The most important markup characters in XML are `<` and `>` - of course. If you want these characters to be part of your content, you'll have to replace them. That is done with *xml entities*.

Within the content, any XML entity will start with an ampersand (`<` comes out as `&lt;`), therefore the ampersand is the third most important special character. If you want an ampersand within the content you must use an entitiy (`&amp;`) as a code for *in this place we want an ampersand*.

You must distinguish between the text you see, when you look at the XML and the actual content taken **out of the XML**.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SomeStringWithSpecialCharacters NVARCHAR(200)=N'This & that -> let''s see, why how some foreign characters behave: அரிச். And what about a line break?' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Here is the second line. And an unprintable?' + CHAR(2);
```

--Here we use `FOR XML`, all the escaping is done implicitly

```
SELECT @SomeStringWithSpecialCharacters AS TestIt FOR XML PATH('test');
```

The result

```
<test>
  <TestIt>This &amp; that -&gt; let's see, why how some foreign characters behave: அரிச். And what about a line break?
Here is the second line. And an unprintable?&#x2;</TestIt>
</test>
```

Now I take the XML as it came out of the first part and place it into a XML-typed variable.
Attention: I had to remove the `&#x2;` entity, check it out...

```
DECLARE @SomeXML XML=
N'<test>
  <TestIt>This &amp; that -&gt; let''s see, why how some foreign characters behave: அரிச். And what about a line break?
Here is the second line. And an unprintable?</TestIt>
</test>';
```

--Now we do the magic using `.value()` against a native XML:

```
SELECT @SomeXML.value('(/test/TestIt/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

The result comes out with all entities re-espaced:

```
This & -> let's see, why how some foreign characters behave: அரிச். And what about a line break?
Here is the second line. And an unprintable?
```

The general hint is: Never do the replacements yourself. Pushing content **into the XML** will need escaping and reading content **out of XML** will need the opposite. All this is done for you implicitly, when you use the proper tools.

Answer (score 0):

'&' is a special character that is being rendered out of ' &amp ; '

The best practice here would be to decode the XML, adding a reference below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads